# Navigation Drawer chamando Activity - Fechar o menu ao clicar no item da Activity se ela for a atual

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Criei um navigation Drawer. Para utilizar em várias `Activities` usando uma classe padrão para ele (`DrawerBase.java`) e extendo ela nas `Activities` onde quero que o Navigation Drawer abra, porém estou com o seguinte problema:

Se estou na Activity Home, abro o menu e clico no item correspondente a activity Home, ela é recarregada, como posso fazer um teste no método `OnNavigationItemSelected()` da minha classe `DrawerBase` para verificar se o item que cliquei para abrir é o da `activity` que já estou e chamar o comando de fechar o `drawer` ao invés de recarregar a `activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usei esse código para fazer o teste antes de chamar a Intent:

```
if (id == R.id.home) {
    if(this.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("HomeActivity")){
       drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    }else{
       Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes fazer isso de outra forma, adicionares no manifest uma regra:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Home"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Assim já não vai recarregar a mesma atividade de novo.